# Routing Conflict in Codeigniter application with other assets in root folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes, codeigniter-3

Hi I have Codeigniter Web App.

I am Facing conflict between my route and an asset(Image or some file) with exact name as my route name.

My asset is opening in browser when i am trying to access my route. I know the solution can be achieved with htaccess but i simply not getting it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Check my Folder Structure Below:

```
Root
 - application
 - system
 - assets
   event.png
   list.html
```

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R]
```

My route is www.example.com/event/event-name

I am facing issue here.

Comment: Show `.htaccess`.

Comment: @Tpojka i updated my question with htaccess

Comment: Side note: I always see (and use) forcing www/non-www as first rule. Try to set it just after Options leaving index.php rewrite as last one.

Comment: @Tpojka this wont solve the problem i guess, any way if this is good practice i will make note of it thanks.

Comment: Try with adding one more conditional line before 'not a file' rule: `RewriteCond $1 !^(*\.png)`.

Answer (score 1):

Find and replace usages of event.png, and rename it!

OR, reconfigure your route. You can use regex to ensure your route doesn't accept a .png in it. See here https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Comment: this is not the correct way i guess, there might be some work around. and it is not even going to core files since my asset file is in root folder.

Comment: The "correct way" is not a work around. I just tried to replicate this behavior and can't. So something else is going on. The easy solution is to rename the event.png to something else as suggested. You have something wrong somewhere. You can maybe show us the contents of your routes config file and the event controller. Otherwise, this answer is the quickest and easiest fix.

Comment: @Joe i already fixed this before he suggested, now i am looking for permanent solution :)

Comment: Can we see the controller, then? There's absolutely nothing that should be telling it to look in the root for an image file when you're trying to call a controller method.